# resultSet no me devuelve nada

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, stored-procedure

buen día.

Estoy tratando de llamar a un procedimiento almacenado de `sql server` desde `java`, pero al momento de consultar, no me devuelve nada.

este es mi procedimiento almacenado.

```
USE [Personal]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_obtenerlistadocentrosid]
@id_centro INTEGER,
@id_ciudad INTEGER,
@id_region INTEGER,
@id_seccion INTEGER,
@id_empresa INTEGER
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT
        SCC.numerocentro AS num_centro,
        RTRIM(SCC.numerocentro) AS nom_centro,
        CIU.numero AS num_ciudad,
        RTRIM(CIU.nombreciudad) AS nom_ciudad,
        SR.numero AS num_region,
        RTRIM(SR.nombre) AS nom_region,
        CS.numeroseccion AS num_seccion,
        RTRIM(CS.nombre) AS nom_seccion,
        EMP.clave AS num_empresa,
        RTRIM(EMP.nombre) AS nom_empresa
      FROM   
        sapcatalogoempleados SCE  
        INNER JOIN sapcatalogocentros SCC  ON SCC.numerocentro = SCE.centro  
        INNER JOIN sapcatalogociudades CIU ON CIU.Numero = SCC.NumeroCiudad  
        LEFT JOIN sapregiones SR ON SR.numero = CIU.RegionZona AND SR.numero != 0  
        INNER JOIN sapcatalogopuestos SCP ON SCP.Numero = SCE.numeropuesto   
        LEFT JOIN sapempresas EMP ON EMP.Clave = CAST(SCC.empresa as nvarchar) and  CAST(SCC.empresa as nvarchar) != '*'      
        LEFT JOIN cat_secciones CS ON CS.numeroseccion = SCC.Seccion
      WHERE  
        1=1
        and (@id_centro is null or SCE.Centro IN (@id_centro))
        order by num_centro
    END;
```

Y así es como tengo una función para consumirlo:

```
public ResponseEntity<Centros> obtenerListadoCentros(Centros request){

        ResponseEntity<Centros> response = null;
        try{

            int idCentro = request.getIdCentro().intValue();
            int idCiudad = request.getNumeroCiudad();
            int idRegion = request.getNumeroRegion();
            int idSeccion = request.getNumeroseccion();
            int idEmpresa = request.getNumeroempresa();

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            String storedProcedureName  = "proc_obtenerlistadocentrosid(?,?,?,?,?)";

            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call "+ storedProcedureName + "}");
            callableStatement.setInt("id_centro" , idCentro);
            callableStatement.setInt("id_ciudad", idCiudad);
            callableStatement.setInt("id_region", idRegion);
            callableStatement.setInt("id_seccion", idSeccion);
            callableStatement.setInt("id_empresa", idEmpresa);
            ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery();


            int aRows = resultSet.getRow();
            log.info(String.valueOf(aRows));

            while (resultSet.next()){
                Centros em = new Centros();
                em.setIdCentro(resultSet.getLong("num_centro"));
                em.setNombreCentro(resultSet.getString("nom_centro"));
                em.setNumeroCiudad(resultSet.getInt("num_ciudad"));
                em.setNombreCiudad(resultSet.getString("nom_ciudad"));
                em.setNumeroRegion(resultSet.getInt("num_region"));
                em.setNombreRegion(resultSet.getString("nom_region"));
                em.setNumeroseccion(resultSet.getInt("num_seccion"));
                em.setNombreseccion(resultSet.getString("nom_seccion"));
                em.setNumeroempresa(resultSet.getInt("num_empresa"));
                em.setNombreempresa(resultSet.getString("nom_empresa"));
                response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(em);
            }

        }catch (Exception ex){
            log.error("Error: ".concat(ERROR_CONEXION_PERSONAL), ex);
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            throw new PostBadRequestException(ERROR_CONEXION_PERSONAL, ex);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Así es como consulto el procedimiento, lo cual sí obtengo los datos solicitados

```
--obtener listado de centros
EXEC proc_obtenerlistadocentrosid @id_centro = 231888, @id_ciudad = 0,
@id_region = 0, @id_seccion = 0, @id_empresa = 0
```

Comment: Si el SP no devuelve nada, eso se traduce a que el query no devuelve nada. Con la información que das, lo que se puede decir es que ningún registro cumple con la condición. Entiendo que tú esperas que si devuelva algo, pero sin ver un ejemplo de los datos o una mejor explicación de la situación y por qué tu esperas que si devuelva datos, no creo que haya nada que decir.

Comment: Mi sugerencia es que vayas depurando la consulta. Suele encontrarse problema con algún join (quizás tienes inner join y no hay coincidencias, por lo que podría ser outer), así que puedes empezar comentando todos los joins, y vas agregándolos y ejecutando la consulta cada vez hasta detectar el join problemático. También puedes hacer lo mismo con las condiciones de la cláusula where. Entre estas dos es que se excluyen (filtran) registros, por lo que si lo haces ordenadamente, vas a encontrar el origen del problema sin lugar a dudas.

Comment: ¿Tu Stored Procedure devuelve datos si la pruebas directamente en el manejador de base de datos? Si es así, entonces deberías revisar el valor de los parámetros que estás pasando desde Java. Por cierto, en tu SP defines 5 variables, pero solamente usas una de ellas. ¿Cuál es el sentido de las otras cuatro?

Comment: Sí, si me devuelve los datos solicitados.  En tema de las 5 variables,  es de requisito que ponga las 5 pero al menos 1 tiene que tener información .

Comment: Prueba a poner marcadores por el índice, en vez de por el nombre, para vincular los datos. Algo así: **`callableStatement.setInt(1 , idCentro); callableStatement.setInt(2, idCiudad); callableStatement.setInt(3, idRegion); callableStatement.setInt(4, idSeccion); callableStatement.setInt(5, idEmpresa);`**